# linux cmd for searching file(.csv) by column name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the Linux :

So, csv's having:
Id, Profession, and so on the columns name ...

I have to select specific .csv files by column name {'Profession' => 'Teacher'}.
how to run cmnds in linux ?
I tried to use grep but doesn't work the way I want.

Comment: Post a bit of the file so people can help you, and what kind of Linux - Ubuntu? CentOS? Mint?

Comment: Depending on the detailed format (embedded quotes/double quotes? embedded commas?) of your CSVs your of the mill command line tools may be a poor choice.  If the format is simple, and none of the potential delimiters are within fields you could attack the files w/ awk.  Your "question", as it stands, doesn't offer itself for an answer - lacking input, as @user2182349 pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

if all we know is that column name and an input file with first line the column names followed by the data, here is a start. I am not coding for lack of 100 % clarity. 
We have the column name as a script parameter. We must determine the number of that field in the CSV file. It can be done by a case statement. 
Now, if we know that column number, say 5, it's easy to use the cut command. 
cut - d", " -f5 specific .csv

Answer (score 0):

So I think you want to grep the first line of the csv and return it if it has a certain one. But I can't tell if your question is saying you also want to transform it to a new one. If you just want the former you can do:

```
echo $(find . -name '*csv' -exec head -n1 {} \;) | grep Tuesday
```

However if you would like to do the latter:

```
for i in $(find $(pwd) -name '*csv'); do sed -i '1s/Profession/Teacher/g' $i; done
```

You will need to use gsed if on Mac.